# Represent circuit using one AND and one OR gate

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

How do you make the logic circuit for the following equation using one AND gate and one OR gate?

F=(V+W+Y+Z)(U+W+Y+Z)(W+X+Y+Z)

Comment: You can transform the equation and simplify it, for example using (a+b).(a+c) = a.a+a.b+a.c+b.c = a+b.c

Answer (score 1):

You look carefully at the equation and simplify it.  I haven't actually worked it all the way thru (this is *your* homework, not mine), but I can see some obvious simplifications from inspection.

Spend a little time and actually *look* at the equation.

Comment: I have taken a lot of time to look at it, as well as confer with other people in my class, and we are stuck too, so stop implying I'm just going here to get my homework done.  Also, maybe they're not obvious to everyone, so quit being condescending.

Comment: @peev: You *still* haven't shown what you've done, where exactly you're stuck, or actually any effort at all.

Comment: You're still being condescending in your response, and I suggest you fix that.  I don't need your help anymore, since the comment on my question answered it immediately.  I don't need to answer to you at all, but I will to show you were jumping to conclusions and blowing me off as a lazy college student.  The answer is F=UVX+W+Y+Z, because of the distributive law F=(A+B)(A+C).  I was trying to expand it and simplify it from there, since I am new to the topic.  So instead of immediately assuming the worst of someone asking a question, just try to help them.

Comment: @pee: You seem to think it's OK just dump a homework problem on us and expect us to give you the answer without demonstrating any effort on your part.  It doesn't work that way.